# What are crowns?

Tags: nuclear-throne

I've seen the text [RUSH CROWN] and others in the lower right corner of screenshots from Nuclear Throne. What does this mean and is it something I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Crowns are secretly located **game modifiers**, found in hidden **Crown Vaults**. In order to access a Crown Vault you need to destroy a fully charged Proto Statue, this will spawn a portal to the Crown Vault. Right now, after picking up a crown, you get to choose one crown effect out of a list of all of the crowns (this may change). You can also choose to not take a crown at all. Crowns only last for your current run and disappear after restarting which also might be changed.

There are 12 crowns:

- Crown of Life - Enemies no longer drop medkits
- Crown of Haste - Pickups fade faster, worth more
- Crown of Risk - More pickups at full health, fewer pickups when damaged
- Crown of Guns - Enemies drop guns instead of ammo
- Crown of Destiny - Immediately get a random mutation, all future mutations also random
- Crown of Curses - More cursed chests
- Crown of Hatred - Chests give rads and deal damage
- Crown of Blood - More enemies, fewer rads
- Crown of Love - Weapon chests and rad canisters become ammo chests
- Crown of Luck - Start each level with 1 hp, some enemies will have 1 hp
- Crown of Death - More explosions, lose 1 max hp
- Crown of Protection - Walking over weapons gives hp instead of ammo

---

A full list of the benefits each crown gives can be found [here](http://nuclear-throne.wikia.com/wiki/Crowns).